# Предлоги о и об

Tags: предлоги

Недопустим пропуск разных предлогов; ср.:

на предприятиях и в учреждениях.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.(Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.(%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C) Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.)

СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ

"Невозможен пропуск разных предлогов; ср.: на предприятиях и в учреждениях. Иногда по недосмотру предлог в этом случае опускается при длинном ряде однородных членов, когда вначале такой пропуск возможен, а в дальнейшем невозможен, например: «Много народу было на улицах, площадях, бульварах, переулках» (перед последним словом нужен уже другой предлог)".

Значит, надо писать: договор о торговле и об инвестициях?

Указ "Об утверждении Государственной программы инфраструктурного развития и внесении дополнения". Здесь надо: о внесении?

Впрочем, есть ответ:

"Во вторник и четверг" или "во вторник и в четверг"? Можно ли опустить предлог перед словом "четверг"?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Второй предлог следует опустить: во вторник и четверг.

Следовательно предлог "об" не нужен.

Comment: doom, можно попросить приводить ссылки на источник ваших рекомендаций?! Мало ли какое вы положение откопаете, да и контекст важен обычно.

Comment: (+) Я имею в виду положения типа *Недопустим пропуск разных предлогов* и подобных императивных требований, которые вы выносите в преамбулу вопроса. .

Answer (score 1):

"О" и "Об" - это две формы одного предлога (и еще "обо"). Так что напрямую тут положение о недопустимости пропуска неприменимо. Хотя иногда и бывает, что из соображений наглядности лучше его применить.

Здесь - да, лучше бы "ОБ" не убирать, поскольку две составные части Указа "внесение" и "дополнение" не представляют единого целого (ну на первый взгляд, что за указ в реале, мне не ведомо), скорее даже противопоставляются друг другу. Поэтому объединять их под одним союзом действительно не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение "договор  о торговле и  инвестициях" вполне возможно, звучит нормально.

Указ "Об утверждении Государственной программы инфраструктурного развития и о внесении дополнения". Здесь надо "о внесении". Согласна с behemothus.

Answer (score 1):

Это выражение **применяется часто и обычно с одним предлогом**, так как предлог ОБ в большинстве случаях является только  **фонетическим вариантом** предлога О, например:

Соглашение **о торговле услугами и инвестициях** в государствах - участниках Единого экономического пространства прекратило действие с 01.01.2015 на основании международного договора от 29.05.2014.

Вашингтон давит на Европу насчет соглашения о **свободной торговле и инвестициях.**

**Из словаря**

ОБ, предлог. 1. **Употр. вместо "о"** : перед словами, начинающимися **с гласной**, например: об армии; в отдельных выражениях перед словами, начинающимися с согласной, например: рука об руку,  2. Употр. наряду с "о" перед словами, начинающимися с йотированной гласной, перед местоимением "их" и иногда в **разговорной речи** перед словами, начинающимися с согласной, например: об их деле, об липу.

Answer (score 0):

Вы подняли большую тему влияния чиновного сословия на русскую речь (впрочем, это - для любого языка). Они пишут свои Указы и исходят из своей логики. Порой подменяют не только правила приличной фонетики (вспомните несчастную букву Ф в разных аббревиатурах от ФСБ до ФМС и РФФИ): ведь тут чиновники не просто навязывают обществу своё Фэ, но и формируют свои сословные правила речи. Так вот и здесь, в случае с Указом. Почему бы не покомандовать предлогами, если они управляемы? А мы можем просто на форумах ворчать...